# What is VM_BUG_ON_PAGE(PageLRU(page) || PageUnevictable(page))?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, crash, kernel, embedded-linux

```html
[   19.492487] page dumped because: VM_BUG_ON_PAGE(PageLRU(page) || PageUnevictable(page))
[   19.500551] page->mem_cgroup:be008c00
[   19.504226] ------------[ cut here ]------------ //kernel panic here
[   19.508851] kernel BUG at mm/vmscan.c:1350!
[   19.513032] Internal error: Oops - BUG: 0 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
```

Please let me know what does it error message means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that, The page you requested is locked by some another process.so that is unevictable flag on that page.

For example.

If you reserved the CMA area of 512MB, From CMA area any process can use pages(only MOVABLE PAGES), if the process takes page as movable page from cma area, but locked(VM_LOCKED) that page using mlock() after acquiring page,but when CMA area is requested the contiguous are than it fails to migrate that locked/pinned page.

It is stable kernel bug(4.12+) :
[patch-link](https://ozlabs.org/~akpm/mmotm/broken-out/mm-fix-trying-to-reclaim-unevicable-lru-page.patch)